# Accessing Internal Custom WebServices of Sharepoint

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, iis

I'm a new to sharepoint and IIS. recently, I've got a SP solution bundle which has got a web service located in Layouts folder. I managed to successfully deploy the solution.
The problem is I'm not able to access the webservice in solution, as I guess I might missing some stages in deployment.

I deployed the Solution directly from visual studio to my desired web application on sharepoint server. The service file has already been placed at  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\template\layouts\MyFolder\ServiceName.asmx

However, once I try to call it cannot being accessed via application url:

```
http://localhost:9999/_layouts/MyFolder/ServiceName.asmx
```

Do I need to set anything in order to be able to access the service via desired url?

Answer (score 0):

I just got it. I did deploy Bundle on Sharepoint 2013 and I just realized it goes under _layout/15/MyFolder!
I have fixed my problem anyway